# Laravel Route->middleware('auth') for different user types

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

I've been trying to figure out a way to make 3 types of user access to pages:

1. `guest`
2. `admin`
3. `user`

For example:

- guests should only be able to use the routes `/homepage` and `/login`
- admins should only be able to use the routes `/homepage`, `/logout` and `/manage`
- users should only be able to use the routes `/homepage`, `/logout` and `/shopping/cart`

`Guest` is not signed in. `Admin` and `User` share some routes, but not all routes should be equal access between the 2

I've been using a workaround in the views to show 3 separate displays:

```php
@auth
    // Paragraph seen by the user with name `admin`
    @if(auth()->user()->attribute == 'admin')
        <p>ADMIN</p>
    // Paragraph seen by every other user
    @else
        <p>USER</p>
    @endif
// Paragraph seen by guests
@else
    <p>GUEST</p>
@endauth
```

This serves the purpose of hiding things on the page using the `attribute` value of the user, but I want a way to apply the 3 access tiers on entire routes since regular users can get access to management pages.

Comment: what distinguishes these "types" of users ... the name? roles?

Comment: I am manually seeding the users to the users table in the database with an `attribute` column. That value defines whether they're an admin or user

Comment: what column are you using to distinguish this?

Comment: it is named `attribute`

Comment: you have a column named `attribute` that holds one of these 3 values? ... you could look into authorization then you could use the `can` middleware

Comment: one of the 2 values, the 3rd is a non-logged in user,

Comment: well for the `homepage` you don't need any middlleware ... `login` gets the `guest` middleware by default already ... `logout` would just have the `auth` middleware, as per default ... basically you are just down to an 'admin' checking middleware since logged in users would just be checked by the `auth` middleware in general besides that

Comment: `auth` doesn't distinguish between the two signed in users, it gives both `admin` and `user` equal access to routes, which is what I want to separate for certain pages

Comment: which is why all you have to do is check if they are admin or not as `auth` already takes care of the 'regular' user part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252313/discussion-between-dancchi-and-lagbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle it with guards instead.
in config/auth.php  define your desired guards like below:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver'   => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'adminapi' => [
        'driver'   => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver'   => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

the define the providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => Modules\User\Entities\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => \Modules\Operator\Entities\Operator::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

after that you can use it in your code like this:

auth()->guard('admin') ? print('admin') : print('user')

or in your blades with with @auth directive

you can get more info[here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Youre after something like this

```
@if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
 Admin
@elseif(Auth::guard('user')->check())
User
@else
     @guest()
    Guest
     @endguest
@endif
```